# Get data from SELECT

Tags: php, jquery, get, http-post

Let's say I have this:

```
<select name="exposure">
                         <option value='1,0.005'>Micro</option> 
                         <option value='2,0.007'>Mini</option> 
                       </select>

                       <select name="clicks">
                          <option value="2500">2500 - Clicks</option >
                          <option value="500">500 - Clicks</option >
                        </select>

                        <label>Price:</label>

                        <div id="price"></div>
```

How can I do, so whenever I select something from `select="exposure"`, it will automatically change the OPTIONS of `select="clicks"`, and at last, take the value from select="clicks" and then multiply it with the second value of `select="exposure"`.

**Example**

I have selected

```
<option value='2,0.007'>Mini</option>
```

And with this option, the only click package that is available is:

```
<option value="2500">2500 - Clicks</option >
```

Price: 0.007*2500 = 17,5

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("select[name=clicks]").change(function(){
   $("label").text( parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($("select[name=clicks]:option:eq(1)")[0].value) );
});
```

Comment: No sorry, not what I am looking for. I don't just want to do the math, I want to: How can I do, so whenever I select something from select="exposure", it will automaticlly change the OPTIONS of select="clicks", and at last, take the value from select="clicks" and then multiply it with the second value of select="exposure"

Comment: Will the options in `clicks` dropdown change on change of `exposure` dropdown? If yes do we make an ajax call to get the news options

Comment: Yes, the options in click will change, when the option of exposure change. I am just not sure how to do this.

Comment: From where do you get the new options for `clicks` dropdown? Do you have any sevice or page to call and get the options?

Comment: I get the options from the click and the exposure SELECT from a mysql query. But I guess, I could make a new page to get the functions with?

Comment: If the options are dynamic then you have to make a ajax call and get the options by passing the selected exposure.

Comment: You have to create a new php page which will look for exposure request param and make a DB call to get the clicks and send a json string as a response. We can make an ajax call to this php page passing the selected exposure and then get the clicks json response. Using this we will populate the clicks dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To "select value of select":

```
$('select[name="exposure"]').val('2,0.007');
```

To make only some options available:

```
$('select[name="clicks"] option[value="500"]').remove();
```

To extract data from value:

```
var splitResult = $('select[name="exposure"]').val().split(',');
alert(splitResult[0] * splitResult[1]);
```

But I personally suggest to not pass additional information via the attribute "value"; better solution would be to create a new attribute to such needs.